# How to sort an array which contains objects with chars and decimals?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

To sort my array I use this method:

```
self.myArray = [self.myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[ObjectVO class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[ObjectVO class]]) {
        ObjectVO *myObject1 = (ObjectVO *)obj1;
        ObjectVO *myObject2 = (ObjectVO *)obj2;
        switch (sortType) {
        ....
           case 2:
           return [myObject1.name compare: myObject2.name];
        .....
        }
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

The problem is when I have 2 objects like: **A100** and **A50**, A100 is the first object in the list and A50 is the second object.
My objects are stings.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are not doing any comparison. the place you say // my code. add the comparison code in there.

Comment: are you trying to sort hex-decimal?

Comment: @hasan83 I wrote that my objects are string. Not in all cases my string contains numbers too, but in other it did. So I have to solve that cases.

Comment: You solve the problem by holding the data in a more appropriate type.  In this case a custom class with column/row members.  Then implement `IsEqual` on that class.

Comment: first in your question you said that your code sorts an array. but, it sorts it wrong. actually you are not doing any sorting at all. 2nd, you didn't say what is the sorting criteria.

Comment: @hasan83 I said I sort an array with string objects. I didn't write the whole code of sort, because you have to know how it looks when you see the name of the method. Now I added more details about my code.

Comment: :) the point of stackoverflow is to add your trials and ask for fix. Also questions should be clear we shouldn't guess. Obviously your question isnt thats why you got two down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.myArray = [self.myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

`NSNumericSearch`

> Numbers within strings are compared using numeric value, that is,
>   Name2.txt < Name7.txt < Name25.txt.
>
> Numeric comparison only applies to the numerals in the string, not
>   other characters that would have meaning in a true number such as a
>   negative sign or a decimal point.
>
> This option only applies to compare methods, not find.